# How to say "this" inside a hilt method without encountering cyclic dependency?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I have a ClassA which depends on ClassB but ClassB has a listener interface which is implemented by ClassA. How can I tell Hilt that I need ClassA while creating ClassB without facing dependency cycle error?

My class structure:

```
class ClassA(val classB: ClassB): IClassBListener

class ClassB(val classBListener: IClassBListener)

interface IClassBListener{}
```

What I tried is below which gives dependency cycle error as I expected:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideClassA(classBListener: IClassBListener): ClassA = ClassA(ClassB(classBListener))

@Binds
abstract fun bindClassBListener(classA: ClassA): IClassBListener
```

In ***funProvideClassA*** method, I need to return something like ***ClassA(ClassB(this))*** where "this" is the ClassA that Hilt creates. How can this be possible?

Comment: With these class definitions it isn't possible, with or without Hilt. You can't get an instance of A unless you have an instance of B, but instantiating B requires A. I'd suggest rethinking why you need this kind of cycle and see if you can express your code differently to avoid it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @gpunto I need a structure like where fragment listens recycler view adapter's on click method. For this example's purpose, you create a recycler view adapter inside the fragment and inform the fragment via an interface when a recycler item is clicked. I try to achieve a similar functionality to this. I can construct ClassB inside the ClassA manually (like where you create recycler adapter inside a fragment) and this will work perfectly but I try to use Hilt for this.

Comment: @bugra Are you trying to create Fragment and Adapter objects using Hilt?

Comment: @ArpitShukla no, it was just an example for the functionality I try to achieve.